# Why doesn't JS always bind `this` to `foo` when foo.fn() is called?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, binding, this

I think JavaScript ES6's arrow functions have two changes:

1. get rid of the "lost binding issue".
2. make `this` not bind to `foo` when `foo.fn()` is called.

For (1) above, the following code can illustrate (running inside of Node console):

```
var peter = { 
    name: "Peter Pan", 
    greetLater: function() { 
        setTimeout(function() { 
            console.log("Hi my name is", this.name); 
        }, 0);
    }
};

peter.greetLater();  // => Hi my name is undefined

var michael = { 
    name: "Michael J Fox", 
    greetLater: function() { 
        setTimeout(() => { 
            console.log("Hi my name is", this.name); 
        }, 0);
    }
};

michael.greetLater();  // => Hi my name is Michael J Fox
```

For (2) above, the following code can illustrate:

```
var winona = { 
    name: "Winona Ryder", 
    greet: function() { 
        console.log("Hi my name is", this.name);
    }
};

winona.greet(); // => Hi my name is Winona Ryder

var demi = { 
    name: "Demi Moore", 
    greet: () => { 
        console.log("Hi my name is", this.name);
    }
};

demi.greet(); // => Hi my name is undefined
```

I can understand (1) is a good thing as it solves the "lost binding" issue. But (2) is like "cutting the binding". It might seem that (2) is to solve the issue of (1), which is to go up the lexical scope to find `this`, but I think having (1) and not having (2) can co-exist: that is, when `foo.fn()` is called, the `this` inside the code of `fn()` can still refer to `foo`.

What is wrong with when `foo.fn()` is called, the `this` inside the code of `fn()` can still refer to `foo`, and when it is "dangling function", as in the `SetTimeout()` in (1) above, or in the following code:

```
winonaGreet = winona.greet;
winonaGreet(); // => Hi my name is undefined
```

then it uses the new behavior of going up the lexical scope to find the `this`?  Isn't this more coherent with everything?

That is, when it is `fn()` or passed to `SetTimeout` and stored as `fn` and later invoked as `fn()`, then look up the lexical scope, but for `foo.fn()`, it just make a lot of sense to bind `this` to `foo` instead of looking up the lexical scope.

Why would we have 2 new rules, one to keep the binding and one to cut it?

And it seems for (2), the ways we can still call `foo.fn()` and have `this` inside of `fn()` bind to `foo` is to not use arrow function, or use ES6's `class`, as in [Mozilla's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  // Getter
  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }
  // Method
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

but then, when we have (1), why do we have (2) also? It is like a hybrid of most other languages, where if `foo.fn()` is called, the `this` is always bound to `foo`.

Comment: In this, `greet: () => {`, `this` will not refer to `demi` but to the function it is defined in

Comment: @Rajesh the thing is, why do we have to have that behavior?

Comment: There is only one case, one simple rule, it doesn't matter in what context you use the arrow function. It get `this` from outer scope. if you don't have outer scope, `this` will be undefined. If you want object with function and have this you can use normal function.

Comment: @jcubic I guess if you look at it this way, then one rule. Now, it is changing the behavior of the old JS in *two* ways

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Arror functions bind current scope to parent. A scope is associated to a function. So when you use arrow function, you are binding the function's `this` in which it is defined

Comment: it's not changing old behavior because you're using arrow function, old behavior is when you normal function that work the same as before.

Comment: Also this is not some kind of object that have arrow function, it's the same arrow function that is "expression" that's assigned to object property. This expression work the same in any context you use it. it's like `demi.fn = () => console.log(this);`, if this would work like you expect what is the this then `function Person() { demi.fn = () => console.log(this); } new Person()` that way there is only one rule for arrow function as expression, and `this` is Person instance not `demi`.

Answer (score 1):

**this and Arrow Functions:**

> Arrow functions, introduced in ES6, provides a concise way to write functions in >JavaScript.
>   Another significant advantage it offers is the fact that it does not bind its own this. In other words, the context inside arrow functions is lexically or statically defined.

What do we mean by that?

> Unlike other functions, the value of this inside arrow functions is not dependent on how they are invoked or how they are defined.It depends only on its enclosing context.

Thus, regardless of whether the arrow function was called using function invocation or method invocation, it retains the value of this from its enclosing context.In other words, an arrow function’s `this value` is the same as it was immediately outside it.

If used outside any enclosing function, an `arrow function` inherits the global context, thereby setting the value of `this` to the global object.

Comment: so `rectangle.calcArea()` can have two different behaviors if rectangle is an object literal with arrow function, vs if it is a `class` object. That is quite confusing and can have unexpected results

Comment: So I guess one new rule: arrow functions does have `this` but always go to one outer scope and start looking for it, up and up the scope. So this one new rule, two changed behaviors: (1) lost binding bound, (2) bound binding lost... or (1) lost binding tight (2) tight binding lost

Comment: Yaa , we can say that beacuse arrow function’s this value is the same as it was immediately outside it  . @太極者無極而生

Comment: correction above: So I guess one new rule: arrow functions does **[not]** have `this` but always go to one outer scope and start looking for it, up and up the scope.

Answer (score 1):

In classic function expressions, the `this` keyword is bound to different values based on the context in which it is called.

There are a few subtle differences in behavior between ordinary `function` functions and arrow functions. Arrow functions do not have their own `this` value. The value of `this` inside an arrow function is always inherited from the enclosing scope. 
Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so `this` actually refers to the originating context.

There are a few other differences: arrow functions don’t get their own `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target` keywords. Arrow functions are anonymous, which means that they are not named, so if your function needs to have a self-reference at any point (e.g. recursion, event handler that needs to unbind), it will not work.

More info https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/

Comment: so it is like: arrow function always go to outer scope(s) to look for `this`, even when `foo.fn()` is called and `fn` is an arrow function -- it won't bind to `foo`, but it always go by the outer scope rule. If the above is true, then is it a big warning or lint issue when arrow function is used inside of an object literal? (because not having `this` bind to `foo` for `foo.fn()` is very counter-intuitive)

Comment: I saw in that article: "Arrow functions do not have their own `this` value. The value of this inside an arrow function is always inherited from the enclosing scope." So it is like.. Q: do you have a bow in arrow functions? A: No, arrow functions don't have **`this`**

Comment: I was tempted to think that if arrow functions don't have `this`, then is it not so object-oriented but rather is more functional programming?

Answer (score 0):

A scope in JS is associated to a function. When you create an object using `new`, `this` is created in `constructor`.

```
const foo = new Foo();
foo.fn()
```

In above code, context is created in constructor and `fn` derives its context from `foo`.

How does this work?

A function has an internal property `[[prototype]]`, which stores context. By default it is not set (*or set to default global scope*) and it derives/ overrides context via caller. So in `foo.fn()`, context refers to `foo`. But if you do `var fn = foo.fn; fn()`, here context is of global/default scope.

To avoid this, we use Arrow function. Arrow function does not have an internal context and uses the context it is defined in. So above code `var fn = foo.fn; fn();` will work.

However, if you define Arrow function inside an object literal, it will still point to the parent scope it was defined in and will not fallback to object.

---

**Sample:**

```js
function Foo1() {
  this.fn = function () {
    console.log(this.constructor.name, this);
  }
}

var foo2 = {
  fn: function() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name, this);
  }
}

function test() {
  var foo3 = {
    fn: function() {
      console.log(this.constructor.name, this);
    }
  }
  
  foo3.fn();
}

function test2() {
  var foo3 = {
    fn: () => {
      console.log(this.constructor.name, this);
    }
  }
  
  foo3.fn();
}

var foo1 = new Foo1();
foo1.fn();

foo2.fn();

test();
test2();
```